# Is there a word for evoking jealousy or wanting to?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I see this behavior in my dogs probably the most, where it wants to flaunt something it has, like a toy, in order to try and make me jealous. It's not just the ask for attention, but the behavior to try and incite an emotional response.

Comment: I'm not that big on "theory of mind" as it applies to puppies, but I kinda doubt they would "flaunt" a toy / ball with the intention of making their owner *jealous*. But you could refer to *provocative* or *teasing* behaviour from both bored puppies and people who want to make their partner jealous.

Comment: that is what "flaunt" means on it's own.  Show off for the purpose of creating a reaction of jealousy or something  similar.

Answer (score 1):

**show-off** [shoh-awf, -of] noun http://www.dictionary.com/browse/show--off?s=t

1. a person given to pretentious display.
2. the act of showing off.

note "pretentious" can mean "making an exaggerated outward show; ostentatious" and something "ostentatious" is "in order to impress others" or "intended to attract notice"

also
**exhibitionist**

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just said "to provoke to jealousy" it would work. (Obviously not a single word as you requested but keep reading below...)

For example, this wording is in the ESV translation (and others) of the Greek New Testament. 1 Corinthians 10:22 "Shall we provoke the Lord to jealousy? Are we stronger than he?"

Interesting side note is that the ancient Greek had a single word for it:
[image].  Most English translations go with this multi-word translation of *provoke to jealousy* in 1 Corinthians and other places in the New Testament.

> My dog tried to ***provoke me to jealousy*** through playing with the toy.

Answer (score 0):

In many situations like this I might expect to see the term **"taunt with"**, in the sense of "to taunt [someone] with [something]".  There has been some difficulty finding a suitable definition to cite here, as most do not have this specific usage listed, but it is common where I live.

See here: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taunt+with

"taunt someone with something" -- to tease or tantalize someone with something. 
*Jerry taunted Fran with the plate of fudge. Please don't taunt me with food I shouldn't eat.*